# Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch and Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at: on react native project

Tags: javascript, react-native

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
at FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:207:21)
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (/Users/dds/Downloads/ContractorApp-main/node_modules/metro/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/watchers/NodeWatcher.js:141:12)
at FSWatcher.emit (node:events:513:28)
at FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:213:12) {
errno: -24,
syscall: 'watch',
code: 'EMFILE',
filename: null
a

I run new exiting react native project but I get this type of error I update watchman and doesn't work for me. Please help.